# Built-in or FOSS GUI application for generating a file hash

Tags: macos, security, file, authentication, verify

I would like to know if there's a built-in GUI application in Mac OS X that can generate file hashes (Disk Utility?). If there isn't such a built-in application, does a FOSS alternative exist?  I can accept any application that can generate a file hash as CRC, MD5, or better in the SHA realm.

Additionally, showing how this is done in the application would be a bonus.

Comment: Any specific reason for GUI? There's plenty of CLIs which you can use through Terminal (and drag the file into if that's the issue) but no GUIs. An answer about CLIs wouldn't be useful?

Comment: I'm OK using terminal, but I can't ask creatives for that as it appears a bit scary to them and one false move could mean disaster, like command completion and accidentally hitting the enter key. I'm also not sure if terminal would be locked down by an admin for being too much of a playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quickhash-GUI](https://quickhash-gui.org) seems to be what you're looking for.  It's cross platform meaning it will be the same "workflow" across macOS, Linux, and Windows.

> QuickHash GUI is an open-source Linux, Windows, and Apple Mac OSX
>   graphical interface that enables easy and rapid data hashing of data :
>   text, text files line by line, binary files, file comparisons, folder
>   comparisons, disks and drive volumes (as administrator), Base64 data,
>   as well as allowing files in one folder to be copied to another with
>   data hashing conducted at either side for comparisons and data
>   integrity.

[image]

Comment: And there seems to be a [WIP for making a Debian package](https://github.com/tedsmith/quickhash/commit/21a2e5d8b405606f8f475354fc3256beb8bdc325).

Comment: there is even a brew cask for it `brew cask install quickhash`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find a method of converting general CLI scripts to the GUI, take a look at [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus). Using this application, you can create GUI wrappers around CLI utilities. It's fairly straightforward to make a shasum or md5 wrapper that can allow drag and drop.

However, there are existing applications available to show file hashes (see Allan's answer).

Comment: I think the idea of Platypus is great shell-to-GUI "Swiss Army Knife", but I don't have access to a Mac, and I would need to export the application as well and put it online or email it for them to install.  Pity that I think they trust a website more than me. I'll try to uptick your answer though. It is indeed an option although not specific or ideal for my needs.